# join two model from one model in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i want to fetch record form 2 model (Booking and Message), both model don't have any relation.

i try a lot but its not working 
i used that code ( http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables )

```
    $options['joins'] = array(
    array('table' => 'books_tags',
        'alias' => 'BooksTag',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            'Book.id = BooksTag.book_id'
        )
    ),
    array('table' => 'tags',
        'alias' => 'Tag',
        'type' => 'inner',
        'conditions' => array(
            'BooksTag.tag_id = Tag.id'
        )
    )
);

    $options['conditions'] = array(
        'Tag.tag' => 'Novel'
    );

    $books = $Book->find('all', $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

BookModel:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'BooksTag' => array(
        'foreignKey' => 'book_id'
    )
);
```

TagModel:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'BooksTag' => array(
        'foreignKey' => 'tag_id'
    )
);
```

BooksController:

```
$this->Book->Behaviors->load('Containable');
$this->Book->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'BooksTag' => array(
            'Tag',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do this on many queries. First find the required tag:

```
    $this->loadModel('Tag');
    $tag = $this->Tag->find('first', array('conditions' =>  array('Tag.tag' => 'Novel')));
    $tag_id = $tag['Tag']['id'];
```

Then find `book_ids`:

```
    $this->loadModel('BookTag');
    $book_ids = $this->BookTag->find('list', array('conditions' => 'BookTag.tag_id' => $tag_id, 'fields' => 'book_id, book_id'));
```

Then find books:

```
    $this->Book->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Book.id' => $book_ids)));
```

It is a long code but runs fast and is easy to understand. Another way is to use sub-queries but they are ugly and may slow down your application